# Why does this program result in an InputMismatchException?

Tags: inputmismatchexception

```
private static int[] loadMarks(String fileName) throws IOException {

    int[] marks = new int[94];  
    /* complete */
    Scanner input = new Scanner(fileName);
    for(int i=0;i<94;i++) {
        marks[i]=input.nextInt();
    }
    return marks;
}
```

Comment: is the input supplied a string or an int? Does it work if scanner is initialized within the loop?

Comment: i'm scanning the file that contains numbers only

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
```

Try this, if your goal is to parse the contents of the file and not the actual string fileName